# Building Apache Hive - impossible to resolve dependencies

Tags: java, ant, hadoop, ivy, hive

I am trying out the Apache Hive as per http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/GettingStarted and am getting this error from Ivy:

```
Downloaded file size doesn't match expected Content Length for http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-0.19.0/hadoop-0.19.0.tar.gz. Please retry.
```

This error repeats 4 times for 4 different versions of Hadoop and the build stops.

I have two questions:

1. How can I download these files manually and give them to the build?
2. Why does Hive need 4 different version of Hadoop downloaded just to build the binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by asking on the mailing list:[Re: Building Hive - cannot resolve dependencies](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hive-user/200911.mbox/%3C45f85f70911121249v6bf0b502kf890b1dec1339a35@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Comment: That link doesn't work either ;) Maybe try this one: http://osdir.com/ml/hive-user-hadoop-apache/2009-11/msg00085.html

Comment: I know it's now 6 years later, but this is a great example of why the salient content should be in the answer - both those links are dead.